# COBOL Sequential file I/O

Tags: ubuntu, cobol

I'm creating a program that reads an input file with some student info, then output it to the terminal and an output file.
I also need to calculate the GPA based on the hours and quality points earned.

I am getting the errors:

```
P2.cob: 46: error: PICTURE clause required for 'outRecord'
P2.cob: in paragraph 'ProcessData':
P2.cob: 81: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
P2.cob: 84: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
P2.cob: 87: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
P2.cob: 90: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
```

Any help/tips would help greatly. My input file example & code attached below:

```
MICHAEL RICHARDSON W1234567 FALL2019 CMPS141 INTRO TO JAVA             A 3.00 12.00
MICHAEL RICHARDSON W1234567 FALL2019 ENGL101 FRESHMAN COMPOSITION      B 3.00 09.00
MICHAEL RICHARDSON W1234567 SPNG2020 CMPS220 OPERATING SYSTEMS         A 3.00 12.00
MICHAEL RICHARDSON W1234567 SPNG2020 ENGL102 CRITICAL READING AND WRIT A 3.00 12.00
```

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.  P2.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT myInFile  ASSIGN TO "P2In.dat".
    SELECT myOutFile ASSIGN TO "P2Out.dat".
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD myInFile.
01 RecordDetails.
   03 StudentDetails.
      05 STUDENT-NAME        PIC X(16).
      05 STUDENT-ID          PIC X(9).
   03 SemesterDetails.
      05 SEMESTER            PIC X(9).
   03 ClassDetails.
      05 CLASS-NAME          PIC X(34).
      05 GRADE               PIC X(2).
   05 HOURS.
      07 HOURS-9             PIC 9.99.
   05 FILLER                 PIC X(2).
   05 POINTS.
      07 POINTS-X            PIC X(1) OCCURS 5.
   05 POINTS-9-99 REDEFINES POINTS.
      07 POINTS-9-99        PIC 9.99.
   05 POINTS-99-99 REDEFINES POINTS.
      07 POINTS-99-99       PIC 99.99.
01 CalculatedValues.
   05 CUMULATIVE-GPA-IN      PIC 99v99 VALUE ZERO.
   05 CUMULATIVE-QP-IN       PIC 99v99 VALUE ZERO.
   05 CUMULATIVE-HOURS-IN    PIC 99v99 VALUE ZERO.

FD myOutFile.
01 outRecord.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

01 SWITCHES.
    05 EOF-SWITCH           PIC X VALUE "N".
01 COUNTERS.
    05 REC-COUNTER          PIC 9(3) VALUE 0.
01 CUMULATIVE.
    05 CUMULATIVE-QP        PIC ZZ.99.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
Main.
    PERFORM Begin.
    PERFORM ProcessData.
    PERFORM PrintLines
            UNTIL EOF-SWITCH = "Y".

Begin.
    OPEN INPUT myInFile
    OPEN OUTPUT myOutFile

    READ myInFile
            AT END
                    MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH
            NOT AT END
                    COMPUTE REC-COUNTER = REC-COUNTER + 1
    END-READ.

ProcessData.
    READ myInFile
    AT END
            MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH
    NOT AT END
            IF GRADE = 'A'
                    COMPUTE CUMULATIVE-QP = CUMULATIVE-QP + 4
            ELSE
            IF GRADE = 'B'
 COMPUTE CUMULATIVE-QP = CUMULATIVE-QP + 3
            ELSE
            IF GRADE = 'C'
                    COMPUTE CUMULATIVE-QP = CUMULATIVE-QP + 2
            ELSE
            IF GRADE = 'D'
                    COMPUTE CUMULATIVE-QP = CUMULATIVE-QP + 1
            END-IF.

PrintLines.

    READ myInFile
    AT END
            MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH

    NOT AT END
            DISPLAY CUMULATIVE-QP
    END-READ.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
P2.cob: 46: error: PICTURE clause required for 'outRecord'
```

Like what @Slapout mentioned, you need to tell the compiler how you want output to be formatted.  **But** you don't actually use `myOutFile` so perhaps you could skip that `FD` and `open` statement for now.

```
P2.cob: in paragraph 'ProcessData':
P2.cob: 81: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
P2.cob: 84: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
P2.cob: 87: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
P2.cob: 90: error: 'CUMULATIVE-QP' is not a numeric value
```

The picture for `CUMULATIVE-QP` is `PIC Z9.99` which is a "numeric-edited" variable.  Those are good for displaying something, but you can't use numeric-edited variables for calculations.

What you want are *two* data items:

- One to **store** the cumulative QP and to use in calculations
- One to **display** the cumulative QP

When you want to display the cumulative QP, you would `MOVE` the numeric variable to the numeric-edited variable, then `DISPLAY` that.

Perhaps (after defining `display-qp` with `pic 99v99`):

```
           move cumulative-qp to display-qp
           display display-qp
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first error says:

> PICTURE clause required for 'outRecord'

this is telling you that in your FD for outRecord, you don't have a PIC clause defined:

```
FD myOutFile.
01 outRecord.
```

The compiler needs to know the layout of your output file.